# inserting status for four inputs from select php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have four HTML inputs and a select option. i want to insert the status for the three inputs = "0" and for the selected one  = "1". kindly help me and tell some thing about mysql query for

```
<input  placeholder="Choice A:" name="a">
<input  placeholder="Choice B:" name="b">
<input  placeholder="Choice C:" name="c">
<input  placeholder="Choice D:" name="d">
<select class="form-control" name="select">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
</select>
```

i want the status for a is 1 and for the remaing 0 in Database :

Comment: use `<option value="1">`

Comment: four inputs and one select box??

Comment: what is the type of input box?

Comment: <select class="form-control" name="select[]" multiple="">
    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option value="0">B</option>
    <option value="0">C</option>
    <option value="0">D</option>
</select>

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Knowing this would help answer this better. Seems like you could use just the select options or a radio group.

Comment: type of input is TEXT

Comment: brothers i want to insert the value for the selected one 1 and for the remaining three 0 in the database table

Comment: @ShakilAhmad: means you have 4 options, and select any one? is there any need to textbox??

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you want to achieve but as per your comments you are looking for this:

**HTML:**

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" placeholder="Choice A:" name="a">
<input type="text" placeholder="Choice B:" name="b">
<input type="text" placeholder="Choice C:" name="c">
<input type="text" placeholder="Choice D:" name="d">
<select class="form-control" name="select">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Now">
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
if(count($_POST) > 0){
    $updateZero = array();
    $updateOne = array();
    $selectArr = array('A','B','C','D'); // default array
    foreach ($selectArr as $key => $value) {
        if($value == $_POST['select']){
            $updateOne[] = $value; // store those selected
        }
        else{
            $updateZero[] = $value; // store those not selected
        }
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($updateOne); // selected array
    print_r($updateZero); // remaining array
}
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => A
)
Array
(
    [0] => B
    [1] => C
    [2] => D
)
```

Now you can use these `array` in `MYSQL Statement` as you need.

Comment: Thank you brother....
but your given solution is little bit diffrent.

i want to store 4 choices in a table one of them having status 1 which mean TRUE and the remaining three have status 0 mean False.
if A is selected in the select box than i want its status is 1 in the dadatabase. and zero for the remaining three inputs

Comment: see the above image for example and my achivement

Comment: @shakil-ahmad u can insert four record with separate query. Resultant array provide u two array use one with status 1 and second with status 2